# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on mac

Tags: macos, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to run my code on a Mac computer.  It always works fine on Windows (I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio), but when I run it on a in XCode, the following code sometimes crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
board_t* board_initBoard() {
    board_t* newBoard = (board_t*)malloc(sizeof(board_t));
    newBoard->grid = (square_t**)malloc(11 * sizeof(square_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        newBoard->grid[i] = (square_t*)malloc(11 * sizeof(square_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            if(i * j * (10 - i) * (10 - j) == 0 && (i + j) % 10 > 2 && (i + j) % 10 < 8)
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = black;
            else if(i * j * (10 - i) * (10 - j) == 225)
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = black;
            else if(i == 5 && j == 5)
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = king;
            else if(i * j * (10 - i) * (10 - j) >= 576)
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = white;
            else if((i == 5 && j * (10 - j) == 21) || (j == 5 && i * (10 - i) == 21))
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = white;
            else if(i * (10 - i) + j * (10 - j) == 0)
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = hostile;
            else
                newBoard->grid[i][j] = empty;
        }
    }
    return newBoard;
}
```

The error only happens about 1 in 3 times and it always happens in the second `for` loop, but at random spots. What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: What is `square_t`?  You allocate `grid` as `malloc(11 * sizeof(square_t))`, but it seems like it should be `malloc(11 * sizeof(square_t*))`.

Comment: Adding the asterisk worked.  Thank you, I don't know how I missed that for so long.  And `square_t` is just an enum.